# Calling an HTTP URL every 5 minutes and forever

Tags: mysql, http, url, server

I need to call a certain HTTP URL every 5 minutes. But the problem is, I need a set up where this is done infinitely many times on its own.

I already have a PHP server set up. Can I make it automatically perform this URL call every five minutes on its own using code that combines an infinite loop and system time somehow?

Thanks,

Comment: thanks, just looked it up and it fits my exact requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple to do

- Login via ssh to your server
- type:

  `crontab -e`
- edit the file/insert this line:

  */5 * * * * wget http://www.example.com/whatever_more
- save the file and exit

Now your URL will be called every 5 minutes

More on cronjobs in linux:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron